# Create base class instance in derived class member function when the base class constructor is protected

Tags: c++, constructor, protected, radix, derived

Given the following code:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(){};  // compilation error
public:
    void foo(){cout << "A\n";}; 
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { };
    void foo(){
        cout << "B\n";
        A A(); // OK
        A a1; // compilation error
    }
};
```

If I changed the base class `A` constructor to `public`, the code compiles. How to explain this?

Comment: `A a();` declares a function. Of course that's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

§11.4/1:

> As described earlier, access to a protected member is granted because
>   the reference occurs in a friend or member of some class `C`. If the
>   access is to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), […].
>   **All other
>   accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5). In
>   this case, the class of the object expression shall be `C` or a class
>   derived from `C`.**

In your case, the access is implicit but nonetheless present. We are trying to access `A`s constructor with the (implicit) object argument `a1`. §11/6:

> All access controls in Clause 11 affect the ability to access a class
>   member name from the declaration of a particular entity […]. [ *Note*:
>   **this access also applies to implicit references to constructors, conversion functions, and destructors.** — *end note* ]

However, `a1` is not of type `B` or a class derived from `B`. Hence our above requirement is not met, and access control is not happy.

Comment: Where are refering about "11/4/1, 11.6.."?  Thanks

Comment: @Christine The language standard.

Comment: "_All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression_" What is the implicit expression of a constructor call?

Comment: @curiousguy The object expression is the not-yet constructed object that the constructor is supposed to construct. It's essentially the name of the unconstructed but accessible object.

Comment: @Columbo So, an lvalue referencing a non existing object? (In conflict with the widely held belief that an lvalue refers to an object BTW.) How do you designate the subobjects of a non existing object?

Comment: @curiousguy "lvalue refers to an object" Clearly false. Anyway, that goes beyond this question.

Comment: @Columbo "Clearly false" but a widely held belief. Anyway, the quoted text is BS. There is no implicit expression in a constructor invocation.

Comment: @curiousguy If it's a widely held, false belief, why did you bother citing it? Possibly because you don't really know what you're talking about? :p The object expression is the (not yet constructed) object that the constructor operates on, i.e. the pointee of `this`. I feel like you don't need to hear any of that.

Comment: "A glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function." [**basic.lval**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval) Old version: "An lvalue refers to an object or function." Either way, the idea that an lvalue of object type must refer to an particular object **comes straight from the standard**. Unless you want to discuss stuff that doesn't exist, and their properties and identity. Which would lead to a discussion of Jean-Paul Sartre's ideas.

Comment: @Columbo I checked once again, searched **[class.init]**, there is no mention of implicit an argument passed to a constructor, no implicit `this`, nothing. The claim "All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit) object expression (5.2.5)" is **clearly wrong**.

Comment: @curiousguy Of course lvalues can designate non-existent objects. Think of dangling references, which are not undefined expressions per se. I've written a paper on classification of lvalues, but it hasn't gone beyond WIP yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173785/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-columbo).

Answer (score 2):

In order to create an object, the constructor needed to do so must be accessible. Within a member of `B`, you can access protected members of `A`, but *only* via an object of type `B`. So you can't access the protected default constructor there.

The previous line `A a();` compiles because it declares a function.

Comment: @Christine: Now you've declared a function with the same name as the class; so `A` will refer to the function, and `A a1;` doesn't make any sense. You'd need `class A a1;` to disambiguate.

Comment: Are constructors accessed via an object? Which object would that be? There is no object. It isn't constructed yet.

Answer (score 0):

To allow access to protected methods you can use `friend class`.
An example:

```
class A
{
    friend class B;
protected:
    A(){};
public:
    void foo(){cout << "A\n";}; 
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() { };
    void foo(){
        cout << "B\n";
        A a1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have any class that has a protected or private Constructor, that class is considered "An Abstract Class Object" This means that it represents a concept or an idea of what an object should be like that contains all comment elements. You can not instantiate an object of this type directly! Thus you must inherit from this class who's constructors are public unless if they are abstract as well. The other idea is to be a specialized object that can not be instantiated directly but can be friends to other classes where their methods can instantiate the object, meaning those classes that have friend access to this abstract class would be able to instantiate this object which will live in the life span and scope of the friends class object. Examples:

```
class A {
public: 
    enum ClassType {
        TYPE_A = 0,
        TYPE_B,
        TYPE_C,
        TYPE_D,
        TYPE_E,
        TYPE_F
    };

private:
    unsigned m_uId;
protected:
    explicit A( A::ClassType type ) :
    m_uId( static_cast<unsigned>( type ) {}

    void initialize() = 0; // Purely Abstract - Each Derived Class Must Create This Function
    void cleanup();     
};

class B sealed : public A {
public:
    B() : A( TYPE_A ) {}
    void initialize() override; 
};

class C sealed : public A {
public:
    C() : A( TYPE_C ) {}
    void initialize() override;
};

class D : public A {
protected:
    D( A::ClassType type ) : A( type ) {}          
    void initialize() override = 0;
};

class E sealed : public D {
public:
    E() : D( TYPE_E ) {}
    void initialize() override;
};

class F sealed : public D {
public:
    F : D( TYPE_F ) {}
    void initialize() override;
};
```

Here I demonstrate polymorphic inheritance. Class A & D you can not instantiate objects for, however classes B,C,E & F you can instantiate objects. Because the constructors for A & D are protected any derived class has access to them. With this setup every class has access to A::cleanup() and every class must implement its own ::initialize() override function.

For this next part I will demonstrate the use of using an abstract class that friend classes can use.

```
class Counter {
    friend unsigned Object1::getCount();
    friend unsigned Object2::getCount();
private:
   static unsigned m_uCounter;       
   Counter() { ++m_uCounter; }

public:
    unsigned getCounter() { return m_uCounter; }       
};

class Object1 {
    friend class Counter;
private:
    unsigned m_uCount;
public:
    Object1() : m_uCount( 0 ) {}
    void count() { 
        Counter counter; 
        m_uCount = counter.getCounter();
    }

    unsigned getCount() const { return m_uCounter; }      
};

class Object2 {
    friend class Counter;
private:
    unsigned m_uCount;
public:
    Object2() : m_uCount( 0 ) {}
    void count() {
        Counter counter;
        m_uCount = counter.getCounter();
    }

    unsigned getCount() const { return m_uCount; }
};
```

This code shows how to use an abstract class that can not be declared on its own, but can be used within other classes by being a friend class. In this situation as only a demonstration the sole purpose of the Counter class is to do the work of incrementing. The counter class can not be a stand alone object which doesn't make sense to have, however its use within other classes through the friend declarations allows those classes to have access to its constructor via the function declaration from the outside classes that are declared as friend functions within the abstract class. This kind of setup allows only Object1::getCount() and Object2::getCount() to declare a type of Counter and to have access to Counter::getCounter().

I hope this helps your understanding in Abstract Classes that deal with Polymorphism using inheritance, Abstract Class association via friend use, and how to properly declare a type that is abstract.

In your code in which others had addressed A A(); is declaring a function prototype where A a1; is trying to declare a type of A which is Abstract!

Comment: In the first section of examples I used the world sealed in some of the class definitions what this word does, it tells the compiler that you are not expecting to have any derived types from it. As you can notice with the hierarchy  A is not sealed thus B,C&D derive from it. Both B&C are sealed, yet D is not sealed and E&F are derived from D which are both sealed.

Comment: I don't know if the sealed keyword is available to you or not, but I am using VS2013.